# What counts as "defeat" in the PvP quest "Eliminate 10 Enemies"

Tags: the-secret-world

In the Fusang Projects there is a quest "Eliminate 10 Enemies" with the following text:

> To win the battles of the secret war, objectives must be obtained. To obtain the objectives, enemy players must be defeated to deplete and neutralise their defences.
>
> Tier 1: Help your secret society by defeating enemy players in the secret war.

I have noticed in some instances that I can be standing alone by myself and get kill credit for an enemy dieing, and in some instances I can do most of the damage to an enemy but not get the killing blow and get no credit for the kill.

What counts as 'defeating' an enemy in the Fusang projects?

Comment: It seems to use the same "tap" system as used for NPCs, meaning you only get credit if you were in the group that got the first hit on a player. The colour of the health-bar should indicate this (orange and faded if someone else will get credit). Getting any hits on an untapped player or a player tapped by your group, no matter how minor, seems to be enough for getting the credit when the player eventually dies.

Comment: @Ingmar You should write this up as an answer, it does appear that this is how it works, hadn't noticed the 'group' part of it in fairness until now, explains a lot of the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to use the same "tap" system that is used for NPCs, meaning you only get credit if you were in the group that got the first hit on an enemy. The colour of the health-bar should indicate this (orange and faded if someone else will get credit). Getting any hits on an untapped player or a player tapped by your group, no matter how minor, seems to be enough for getting the credit when the player eventually dies.